# Disable login by name+password on Azure/Microsoft account + only allow login via security token

Tags: azure, security, multi-factor-authentication

I'd like to use 2FA on my account in the "classical" way. The current setup on Microsoft/Azure accounts looks like a security hole to me.

I signed up to Azure and needed a Microsoft account for that (the one used at login.live.com / account.live.com) When setting up 2FA I can choose between security key, app etc. I setup a security key and it works in general BUT I am still able to login with just the account name and password. I can also choose to use only the key for login. This is not how 2FA is supposed to work.

How can I either use name+password and then the hardware token (this it how it works for aws or google accounts) or just use the token without the possibility to downgrade the security to name+password.

Comment: It sounds like you setup passwordless authentication with the security key, not 2FA necessarily. Though for example for me the security key requires a PIN code from me in addition to the key, so two factors are used.

Comment: Is it possible that you did the 2FA consent flow and have whitelisted the browser you are using? Can you check with another browser and device if you are really not asked for a second auth method? Otherwise i would agree with you, that this is not a real 2FA and you should communicate this issue to Microsoft.

Comment: @juunas Yes using the key requires a pin. But I can just choose to not use the key at all and instead login with name+password. The whole point of these hardware tokens is to prevent phishing. No one should be able to just log in with stolen credentials. But at least for the Microsoft account this would still be the case.

Comment: @tector No the browser is not whitelisted. I did not use the 2FA as listed on Microsofts page. The hardware token is not listed under 2FA but another category.

Comment: Yeah so if you setup the key for passwordless auth, you are not setting up 2FA, it's just an alternative login method. Anyway, this is kinda off topic for Stack Overflow where we answer software development problems :\

Comment: Any idea what would be a good place to ask? I don't have paid support so this excludes Azure support. I created a topic on the msdn forum but no answer yet and I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask anyways.